# Revealing the different layers of a shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

Shapefile I am referring to is 'NUTS_RG_03M_2010' which is together with several other shapefiles available in a ZIP file on the Eurostat web site.

[the ZIP file](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/cache/GISCO/geodatafiles/NUTS_2010_03M_SH.zip)

[the available map sets at Eurostat](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/gisco_Geographical_information_maps/popups/references/administrative_units_statistical_units_1)

I am importing NUTS_RG_03M_2010.shp as a vector layer.

[image]

Actually I am interested in the NUTS 2 or 3 level - not the here displayed national level. Now I print this map in a PDF and when I open it I can see the different layers in short intervals displayed - from very fine grained to the national level. The screen shot shows one intermediate level:

[image]

My conclusion is that those levels, layers or whatever it is called are "hidden" somewhere and must be displayable and editable in QGIS. How do I access them?

**My ultimate goal is** to convert a NUTS 3 level layer to GeoJSON or SVG.

Comment: The actual download link is : http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/cache/GISCO/geodatafiles/NUTS_2010_03M_SH.zip

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to convert NUTS3 into JSON or SVG, you may consider using directly this: https://github.com/jgaffuri/Nuts2json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

This shapefile contains multilevel geometries, which means that there is NUTS 1, 2 and 3 in this layer.
To get only NUTS 3, you got to select only those.
In QGIS, right-click on the layer, and click on `Query`
Then, in the `SQL where` clause" field, enter :

```
"STAT_LEVL_" = 3
```

This way, only the NUTS3 will be displayed :)

You can then export this layer to GeoJSON using the `Save As` dialog by right-clicking on the layer.
Or to SVG by using the `Print Composer`

Comment: That did the trick - thanks a lot!
Two more questions: 
1) What SQL (dialect) is this?
2) How do I find out how many levels are available?

Comment: 1) It's a custom SQL-like query language, not offering all the features of a standard SQL DBMS.
2) You can check those levels by looking at the `Attribute Table`, which displays the data associated to geometries. For this, right-click on the layer and click on `Open Attribute Table`

Comment: And a third one :) Saving the layer as SVG works (I find it odd to considers this conversion as "printing") but the <path>s are lacking IDs / attributes. So I don't know what polygon represents which geographic entity and also cannot programmtically reference it. Do you know how to deal with this issue?

Comment: You can get those ids by using the `SimpleSVG` plugin :
Go to `Plugins` -> `Fetch Python Plugins`
Search for SimpleSVG and install it.
It should appear on your Plugin Toolbar, and you ca then use it.

But note that only the ID will be exported into the SVG, not the attributes

Comment: you've been a great help, cheers! ;)

Comment: @RobinC The `Query` (now called Filter in dev) function is the SQL dialect of the provider not a QGIS custom one.  If you are using PostGIS then anything you can do in a PostGIS WHERE you can do in there, using a ogr based layer and it will use OGR SQL syntax, MS SQL layers use T-SQL.